# Can not import a function from a python module

Tags: python, flask, debugging, web-applications

Here **init**.py has a function create_app ans I am not able to import the function in main.py.

I've attached main.py and **init**.py
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6dH9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9YMh.png)

It keeps on giving
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website' (unknown location)

I have tried importing **init** but it isn't working either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Init.py file is in the templates folder as your image shows.**

**You have to import it like this:**

```
from website.templates import create_app
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because of the `from ... import ...` statement, because you are trying to import a folder. To import a file in that folder, use `import website.create_app`, though this will also cause an error because there is no file named `create_app.py`. The correct code would be:

```
import website.create_app
app = create_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the picture, I am assuming this to be the directory structure:

```
Flask-web-app
├── say-hello
├── website
│   ├── static/
│   ├── templates/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── views.py
└── main.py
```

Your main.py should contain:

```
from website import views    #filename should be used here

app = views.app    #considering views.py has an app variable defined

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The issue was in the way you were using relative imports.

Comment: the function(create_app) is defined in __init__.py file but the tutorial says it will make website folder into a package so we can import it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should definitely try to write `if __name__ == "__main__":`in your`__init__.py`. (This will allows the script to be run as a standalone program)

And then you can try to import the function `create_app` in your `main.py` from `__init__.py` by using import create_app from `__init__.py`. I think the problem here is instead of using `import create_app from website` you should try to directly import it from your `__init__.py`

Lastly you can also try to import all of the function from your `__init__.py` by using `from__init__.py import *`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbY4f.png). Hope this could help you!